# How to convert a csv file with a range of IP to CIDR and keep the respective state ISO number in the new format?

Tags: linux, bash, csv, scripting, cidr

I have a CSV file with with a range of IPs and a ISO State number like this:

```
$ cat test2.csv
1.0.0.0 - 1.0.0.255,17
1.0.1.0 - 1.0.3.255,49
1.0.4.0 - 1.0.7.255,17
1.0.8.0 - 1.0.15.255,47667
1.0.16.0 - 1.0.31.255,14614
1.0.32.0 - 1.0.63.255,47667
1.0.64.0 - 1.0.127.255,69710
1.0.128.0 - 1.0.133.255,209
1.0.134.0 - 1.0.134.255,22537
1.0.135.0 - 1.0.154.255,209
...
```

And I need to have an output like this

```
$ test3.csv
1.0.0.0/24 :17
1.0.1.0/24 :49
1.0.2.0/23 :49
1.0.4.0/22 :17
1.0.8.0/21 :47667
1.0.16.0/20 :14614
1.0.32.0/19 :47667
1.0.64.0/18 :69710
1.0.128.0/22 :209
1.0.132.0/23 :209
1.0.134.0/24 :22537
1.0.135.0/24 :209
1.0.136.0/21 :209
1.0.144.0/21 :209
1.0.152.0/23 :209
1.0.154.0/24 :209
...
```

I don't know how to achieve this. I really appreciate your help.

Thanks,

Gus

Comment: Can you please add a little explanation on how to get from your input to output? Please add relevant dataset instead of random lines.

Comment: What are the `/24` and `/23`....?

Comment: What's an "ISO state number"?

Comment: I've figured out what's going on here, but since the OP hasn't bothered to respond to others' comments, I won't bother to answer.

Comment: What I deploying is a PowerDNS with Geobackend. The problem is that geo-backend only work as country level. So I got from MaxMind the List of IPs from City. The country part is already done, but I need to sort out by USA City too. So, The first list (file) is the Maxmind City db already converted from decimal to Ipv4. The column #2 is the "Code" of the city. In a query, Geo-Backend will look at the IP address table to find and match the source IP address (ip address from a customer per say). Then will pass a City Code. This one will match to a 2nd db where all the all the City Codes are.

Comment: It'll look like this

Comment: Ex. for California (ca 209), Miami (mi 17). In a dig, you can see sip.geo.domain.com IN CNAME ca.sip.geo.domain.com, for example, if the customer is located in California. If the customer is in Miami, the it will be sip.geo.domain.com  IN CNAME  mi.sip.geo.domain.com.